# How to implement the code highlight as bootstrap's example

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, google-code-prettify

I found the [bootstrap's code highlight](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html) has a very good style for code blocks.

[image: bootstrap]

I find it using [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), but I tried google code prettify, the style is different:

[image: google-code]

How to implement the same as bootstrap's ?

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if you want code highlighting dynamically at run-time or generated for static use.

The TWBS Bootstrap project uses the static generated method by generating it's content with a [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org) toolset called [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com), the [Liquid Template Engine](https://shopify.github.io/liquid), some [custom code](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/docs/_plugins/highlight_alt.rb), and Markdown file sources.

If you need highlighting generated dynamically then there are a few options available, the most popular beeing:

- [Prism JS](http://prismjs.com)
- [Highlight JS](https://highlightjs.org)